# MAGENTO: How can I export sku, qty and price?

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to export all products.
I used this function to get all skus.

```
function _getConnection($type = 'core_read') {
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName) {
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}
function _getSku() {
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT sku
                FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . "";
    return $connection->fetchAll($sql);
}

/* * ************* CREATE FILE CSV ************************* */
$_skus = _getSku();
foreach ($_skus as $_sku) {
    $string = $_sku['sku'] . "\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

how to change the query so I export SKU, QTY and PRICE ?

Comment: Hi Dilyan! I want to do the exact same thing. Can you share your whole code for how you managed to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price');

foreach($productCollection as $product) {
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
    $string = $product->getSku() . " - " . $product->getPrice() . " - " . $stockItem->getQty()  . "\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND);
}
```